# Does the Elasticsearch Transport Client for Java API support connection pooling?

Tags: elasticsearch, client, transport

Does the Elasticsearch Transport Client for Java API support connection pooling? I'm using a Spring boot application(elasticsearch repository) that talks to Elasticsearch.